# Return to Home Activity after successfully sending email Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

My app allows the user to enter in information in various fields, take a photo, and then send all the information to a pre-determined email address.

Once they have sent the email, I would like to display a thank you message (probably via Toast) and then take them back to my Home Activity. To use iOS jargon, how do I perform a segue to another screen on successfully sending an email.

EDIT:
I have attempted to implement the solution provided, but not my app is just moving to the next scene, and not sending the email. Have i implemented it incorrectly?

```
if (Witness_response == "Yes"){
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"roadsafety.app@shellharbour.nsw.gov.au"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Dob in a Hoon Report(Y)");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hoon report has been recieved " + emailBody);
                emailIntent.setType("image/*");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose email client..."));
                Intent ReturnIntent = new Intent(dob_in_a_hoon.this, HomeScreen.class );
                dob_in_a_hoon.this.startActivity(ReturnIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on how your application is built, if it is built on fragment swapping you will want to load up the desired fragment. Otherwise you could start a new intent (Activity) like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You could even get away with just calling onBackPressed which will take you back to the previous activity.

Comment: Is there a way I can implement that once the user has sent the email? i.e. at the end of my email intent?

Comment: It performs the intent without send ing the email. See my edited question for my email intent and where I have implemented it - i may have done it wrong.

Comment: Ahh yes I think I see the problem. You should use an asynchronous task to send the email http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html and in the onPostExecute you should make a call back to your original activity to start the new intent. If that doesn't make sense let me know and I will explain further.

Comment: yeah, I think I'm going to need a bit of an example and explanation on that one.

Comment: Do you know how to write an async task?... if not you should be able to find it pretty easily.  Implement a function in your activity that will perform the desired segue.  Then pass your activity to the constructor of the async task (note: you should probably do this via an interface) and in the onPostExecute of your async task call that function on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet allows you to move from activity B to activity A:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Or like ed209 said, you can go back to previous activity by calling onBackPressed method.